# Calculating significance with data set

Tags: statistical-significance, expected-value

I have a data set of words for which I've calculated the average frequency of every letter (e.g., the letter "a" accounts for 9.8% of letters).

I also have letter frequency data from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) that shows the instance of letters for "all" English words.

What I want to do is compare my percentages and the expected percentages to determine if the variation between the values is significant. Is there a way to do this without having the word counts in the Wikipedia data? What other data would I need? What test would be appropriate?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stats.SE!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  The answers to your questions greatly rely upon the questions you want to ask your data.  Whatever you are testing as the null hypothesis should be your basis for letter frequency.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm looking to show that in my data set of words, certain "rare" letters (such as "J") are used significantly more than what would be expected based on the average rates of word incidence across the English language. So, I guess the null hypothesis is that: the average incidence of letters in my data set is the same as the average incidence of letters across the English language.